# Webpart in Sharepoint 2013 connecting to Dynamics CRM

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, sharepoint-2013

I have developed a webpart in sp2013 for adding new leads into my Dynamics CRM system.

I have tried the code in a consoleprogram and it gives no errors

Deploying works fine but when i add on my sharepoint site i get the error message

":$resource:core,importErrorMessage "
}
I have also tried to exclude parts of the code in order to isolate the problem, and this part seems to be the problem:

```
   _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri("http://win-3a65gmro0pg:5555/MyCrm/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"), null, credentials, null);`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem in your webpart file. Look at the following links. It might help you to sort the issue.

[Link 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010programming/thread/2b9ec1f0-15f5-4b5b-a2d9-a15a1a78444f)

[Link 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/377545/Webpart-importing-error)